# Use another compiler when install R packages with Rcpp and CMake

Tags: cmake, rcpp, configure, autoconf

**What I'm doing** I'm developing an R interface/package for C++ codes with Rcpp and CMake. Because `openmp` and `c++11` should be supported, so I have a preference on compilers.

**Problem** I know that I can always put Makevars under `~/.R` (Unix) to change the compiler R uses when install packages. But as a developer, it is not recommended to do so.

It is recommended to use `configure` file to do that. However, I don't quite know how to achieve this, because I'm writing `configure` file by myself and calling `cmake` inside my `configure`. I don't know what to write in `configure` file to search for a specific compiler.

Hope the description is clear. Thank you.

I have attached my `configure` file content below.

```

```
set -x
set -e

which cmake

rm -rf _builds

# call cmake that will set compiler flags in src/Makevars
# and download dependencies
cmake -H. -B_builds
```

```

Comment: If you are using cmake, you shouldn't be using a configure script.

Comment: Then, how should I configure the compile flags for installation? I did this because it is suggested by the [R-cpp core group](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/699)

Comment: OpenMP and C++11 are supported by default on all platforms supporting it by R itself. That include macOS if you install the recommended toolchain.  What you are doing strikes me as wrong.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't think I quite understand what you mean by `OpenMP and C++11 are supported by default on all platforms supporting it by R itself`. I do understand that R can achieve parallelization via creating multiple processes, which is supported by all platform. But my experience is that if you are using `clang` compiler to install/compile packages that requires `-fopenmp` flag, it will fail. In my case, this is exactly what I would like to do. My C++ code requires `-fopenmp` support, and I would like to figure out a way to change the compiler that `R CMD` system uses. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using CMake for building R packages for quite a while, see https://github.com/rohan-shah/mpMap2 for an example.

I completely bypass the R build system though, so I don't use configure at all.

Comment: Actually, nobody is force to use `configure`.  But even your CMake-based construct use `R CMD INSTALL` and hence the compiler R uses.  What OP wants is possible, but difficult, and generally recommend against.

Comment: Not true. As I said, the CMake build system completely bypasses the R build system. I designed it, I should know. R CMD INSTALL is not used to compile anything in this case.

Comment: You call `R CMD INSTALL` via `cmake`, no?

Comment: Yes, that only *copies* files in this case. I encourage you to install package rohan-shah/mpMap2 on linux and see how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Will check the solution.

Comment: Thank you. I have read your code and successfully installed your package on my machine. This is impressive. My follow up question for that would be, what could I do if I want to install your package using another C/C++ compiler? I know one solution is to put `~/.R/Makevars` file. But is it possible to do a search and automatically select the compiler like `autoconf` and `configure`? Thank you!

Comment: CMake automatically detects the compiler and uses it. Set the environment variables CC and CXX appropriately. Eg. "CC=icc CXX=icpc cmake" ...etc.

Comment: And so does R itself so if you do that (as many of us to switch between `clang++` and `g++`, or different versions, or ..) then you don't even need `cmake` in the first place.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel . How can you change compilers via `R CMD`? Is that what you mean? I don't think you can do something like `CC=icc CXX=icpc R CMD install [R_package]`, right? Thank you!

Comment: @DaBookshah . Thank you for your reply. I understand that you can do `CC=icc CXX=icpc cmake` to change the compiler the cmake uses. However, if I understand it correctly, **this does not affect the `R CMD` system**. What do you think?

Comment: @DaBookshah after hours of reading. Now I understand what you meant. It totally makes sense to me right now. you create a dynamic library using cmake and only use r cmd to link to it. That's what you mean by bypassing r cmd install because you compile the library yourself. Thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you meant to say "only use r cmd to *copy* it". But yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to detect if the compiler supports openmp and C++11.

There are many existing packages using `configure` to detect openmp support. One example is ARTP2 (https://github.com/zhangh12/ARTP2/blob/master/configure.ac), which has been mentioned in the "Writing R extension" as an example. You can also use the configure script in xgboost by me (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/configure.ac) as an example. We leave `OPENMP_CXXFLAGS` blank if the compiler doesn't support openmp.

For C++11 support, you can try `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11`. But this will require a new version of autoconf.

I think you can also try `AC_PROG_CXX` to select compilers, like `icc`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So if I'm going to do everything in configure file. Do I generate the configure file using autoconf and put the configure file will work on different platforms? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what autoconf is about.